# log4j stopped logging to the file,

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in my java application, but after some time without throwing any exception it stopped logging

my log4j configuration is as below.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=com.test.TestFIleAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackUpIndex=200
```

My file appender contains some code to do the zip operation and to specify the log file format and all.

This was logging fine for some time, but suddenly stopped logging , no exception also thrown

can any body tell me what can be the issue?

any body know any log4j related issues like this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's `TestFIleAppender` with uppercase I? Also, did you try to print a test message at INFO level?

Comment: yes, info level traces are coming fine

Comment: Mh... so i'ts logging right? The problem might be something else if exceptions are not thrown.

Comment: any known log4j problems like this

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me. Working one day and then not working the next. I went back and realized I had changed the POM dependencies and did some googling.

When I corrected this issue, my logging returned. I would make sure you have the following artifacts in sync:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer, why your logging is stopping.

First, check the hard disk space, whether this is full.

Than write a testcase in which a thread is polling a logging message of type INFO every second. Than you could check whether this is a space or memory issue.

Please notice: When you programm is waiting somewhere and no thread or action is working, you will not see any loging message. Please check, by debugging, whether a code line is executed in a loop (or as you expected to see messages) in which a logging message should be shown.

This is an example of my log4j properties file. May be is is helpful:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, logfile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p (%t) [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=C:/log/client.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

Comment: actualy disc space and my application is ok, basically my application is server, it able to process requests and all... but trace not printing

Comment: my log4j file is also simiilar... u know any known problems in log4j like this

Comment: Is their a reason, why you are using your own FileAppender?

Comment: i have some logic of createing zipfiles of old log files and appending timestamp to newly created log files and all

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the possibility that log4j is still writing to a file, but that file has been unlinked from its parent directory by your custom appender?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after adding *sardine* library to my dependencies. Then, from one of answers here I added *slf4j-log4j12* library to the dependencies and it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a very rare situation, but I once encountered a similar problem that was caused by use of a [Cloner](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/wiki/Usage). After cloning an object with log4j logging enabled, the logging just stopped working. The solution was to exclude log4j classes from the cloning with:

`cloner.dontClone(org.apache.log4j.Logger.class, org.apache.log4j.LogManager.class,)`